# HTML5 Video texture in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-canvas, html5-video, webgl

Is it possible to use videos as texture for webGL in Safari (I'm not even talking iOS Safari)?? I could not make it work. Here is the most simple code I could come up with to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/bmkb6r9h/3/ and it doesn't work [here](http://krpano.com/ios/bugs/ios8-webgl-video-cors/) either.

It fails as soon as the video source is coming from another domain or subdomain with `SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent` when attaching the video texture with `texImage2D`.

Here is my code (sorry it's a bit long, but it's how webGL goes) Also happy to get comment on how to improve the webGL. I've taken code from https://github.com/hawksley/eleVR-Web-Player that is a great intro to 360 video player.

```js
// get DOM elements
videoContainer = document.getElementById('video-container');
video = document.getElementById('video');
canvas = document.getElementById('glcanvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// load the video, and play on ready
video.load();
video.oncanplaythrough = function() {
  video.play();
  drawScene();
};

gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");

// create and attach the shader program to the webGL context
var attributes, uniforms, program;
var attachShader = function(params) {
  // compile the shaders from the shaders scripts
  var getShaderByName = function(id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

    var theSource = "";
    var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

    while(currentChild) {
      if (currentChild.nodeType === 3) {
        theSource += currentChild.textContent;
      }
      currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
    }

    var result;
    if (shaderScript.type === "x-shader/x-fragment") {
      result = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else {
      result = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    }
    gl.shaderSource(result, theSource);
    gl.compileShader(result);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(result, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(result));
      return null;
    }
    return result;
  };

  fragmentShader = getShaderByName(params.fragmentShaderName);
  vertexShader = getShaderByName(params.vertexShaderName);

  program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Unable to initialize the shader program: " + gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  }
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // get the location of attributes and uniforms
  attributes = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < params.attributes.length; i++) {
    var attributeName = params.attributes[i];
    attributes[attributeName] = gl.getAttribLocation(program, attributeName);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes[attributeName]);
  }
  uniforms = {};
  for (i = 0; i < params.uniforms.length; i++) {
    var uniformName = params.uniforms[i];
    uniforms[uniformName] = gl.getUniformLocation(program, uniformName);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attributes[uniformName]);
  }
};
attachShader({
  fragmentShaderName: 'shader-fs',
  vertexShaderName: 'shader-vs',
  attributes: ['aVertexPosition'],
  uniforms: ['uSampler'],
});

// some webGL initialization
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gl.clearDepth(1.0);
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

positionsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionsBuffer);
var positions = [
  -1.0, -1.0,
  1.0, -1.0,
  1.0,  1.0,
  -1.0,  1.0,
];
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  verticesIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesIndexBuffer);
  var vertexIndices = [
  0,  1,  2,      0,  2,  3,
];
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
              new Uint16Array(vertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

// update the texture from the video
updateTexture = function() {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  // the next line fails in Safari if the video is coming from another domain or subdomain
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB,
                gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
};

// draw stuff in the canvas
drawScene = function() {
  updateTexture();
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionsBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(attributes['aVertexPosition'], 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  // Specify the texture to map onto the faces.
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.uniform1i(uniforms['uSampler'], 0);

  // Draw
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesIndexBuffer);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  // keep looping
  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
};
```

```html
<!-- Fragmend shader program -->
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
varying mediump vec2 vDirection;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vDirection.x * 0.5 + 0.5, vDirection.y * 0.5 + 0.5));
}
</script>

<!-- Vertex shader program -->
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute mediump vec2 aVertexPosition;
varying mediump vec2 vDirection;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0, 1.0) * 2.0;
  vDirection = aVertexPosition;
}
</script>

<div id="video-container" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;">
  <canvas id="glcanvas"></canvas>
  <video preload="auto" id="video" loop="true" webkit-playsinline crossOrigin="anonymous" style="    width: 300px; height: 200px;" controls>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Things work perfectly in Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in Safari. Safari does not yet support CORS (cross origin support) for video. See [this webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135379).

[Video does work in WebGL in Safari if the video is from the same origin](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_video.html).

Comment: yes had seem the bug report. What makes you say it's gonna be fixed soon?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I skimmed and saw a patch but I see now it's harder than it looks

Comment: Ok we'll wait and see, since "Apple does not comment on the timing or content of future releases"

Comment: @gman does that three.js link work for you in recent Safari? It does not work for me :/ I do get a warning: "THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float_linear extension not supported." but no error

Comment: .Yes, it works for me, tested on MacOS 10.15.7 and iOS 14.0.1. Warnings are normal three.js poop while it figures out what features it can support.