# Threejs: Video texture not working in safari

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have a little scene that uses an mp4 video to texture a rectangle:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #282923;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}

.no-highlight {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}

#play {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>I AM ALAN TURING</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0'>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='./assets/main.css'>
    </head>

    <video id='video' crossOrigin='anonymous' loop playsinline controls style='position:fixed; top:-10000px; left: -10000px; width: 512px; height: 256px;'>
        <source src='https://duhaime.s3.amazonaws.com/sketches/A565AC1E351B6A21FF7F005AB6FDE6F7/bass-clip.mp4' type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    </video>

    <body class='no-highlight'>

        <div id='play'>play</div>

        <script type='module'>

            import * as THREE from 'https://duhaime.s3.amazonaws.com/sketches/A565AC1E351B6A21FF7F005AB6FDE6F7/assets/js/three.module.js';

            import { AsciiEffect } from 'https://duhaime.s3.amazonaws.com/sketches/A565AC1E351B6A21FF7F005AB6FDE6F7/assets/js/AsciiEffect.js';
            import { TrackballControls } from 'https://duhaime.s3.amazonaws.com/sketches/A565AC1E351B6A21FF7F005AB6FDE6F7/assets/js/TrackballControls.js';

            var camera, controls, scene, renderer, effect;
            var sphere, plane;
            var play, video, videocanvas, videocanvasctx, texture;

            var start = Date.now();

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.z = 100;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0, 0, 0 );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                effect = new AsciiEffect( renderer, ' .:-+*=%@#', { invert: true } );
                effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                effect.domElement.style.color = 'white';
                effect.domElement.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

                // use effect.domElement for ascii rendering
                document.body.appendChild( effect.domElement );
                controls = new TrackballControls( camera, effect.domElement );
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );


                // video
                video = document.querySelector('#video');
                play = document.querySelector('#play');
                play.addEventListener('click', startVideo);

                function startVideo() {
                    video.play();
                    play.parentNode.removeChild(play);

                    // create the canvas
                    videocanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    videocanvas.height = video.clientHeight;
                    videocanvas.width = video.clientWidth;
                    videocanvas.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
                    videocanvasctx = videocanvas.getContext('2d');
                    videocanvasctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
                    videocanvasctx.fillRect(0,0,video.clientWidth,video.clientHeight);
                    texture = new THREE.Texture(videocanvas);
                    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
                    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( video.clientWidth, video.clientHeight, 32 );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                    scene.add(mesh);
                }
            }

            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }

            function render() {
                var timer = Date.now() - start;
                controls.update();
                effect.render( scene, camera );
                if (videocanvasctx && video.readyState == video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) {
              videocanvasctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
              texture.needsUpdate = true;
            }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works fine in Chrome, but does not run in Safari. Does anyone know why that might be, or what I should investigate to discover the different behavior in Safari? Any pointers would be very helpful!

Comment: ah this seems to be a Safari bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590059/html5-video-texture-in-safari

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 Video texture in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590059/html5-video-texture-in-safari)